# Custom spring security filter not called at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to enable spring security in a spring boot rest services project and I'm getting some problems.

I configured it with this code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

and implemented a custom authentication provider in order to login to LDAP (which has a non standard configuration so I wasn't able to make the default ldap provider works)

```
@Component
public class LdapAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String email = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection();
        String uid = ldap.getUserUID(email);
        if(uid == null || uid == ""){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User " + email + " not found");
        }

        if(ldap.login(uid, password)){

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(uid, null, new ArrayList<>());
        }else{
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;  
        //To indicate that this authenticationprovider can handle the auth request. since there's currently only one way of logging in, always return true

    }

}
```

This code is working fine, in the sense that calling my services with a basic authorization header it is able to correctly login and return the service called. The problems started when I tried to insert a different authorization/authentication. Instead of using the basic authentication I would like to pass the credential from a form in my react front end, so I would like to pass them as a json body in a POST call. (the idea is then to generate a jwt token and use that for the following communication).

So I changed the configure method to this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

and defined a custom authentication filter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException{
        String requestBody;
        try{
            requestBody = IOUtils.toString(req.getReader());
            JsonParser jsonParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
            Map<String, Object> requestMap = jsonParser.parseMap(requestBody);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate( new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(requestMap.get("email"), requestMap.get("password"), new ArrayList<>()));
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Something goes wrong parsing the request body",e );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException{

        JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider = new JwtTokenProvider();
        String token = tokenProvider.generateToken(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwt",token);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        res.addCookie(cookie);

    }

}
```

Problem is, whatever I'm doing, the runtime doesn't seems to enter in this filter at all. What am I missing? I guess is something big and stupid but I can't figure it out...

**UPDATE:** the problem seems to be that the UsernamePassWordAuthenticationFilter can be called only through a form. I then change my code to extend AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter instead.

The modified filter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends
        AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super("/api/secureLogin");
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException{
        String requestBody;
        try{
            requestBody = IOUtils.toString(req.getReader());
            JsonParser jsonParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
            Map<String, Object> requestMap = jsonParser.parseMap(requestBody);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(requestMap.get("email"), requestMap.get("password"), new ArrayList<>()); 
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Something goes wrong parsing the request body",e );
        }
    }
}
```

and the modified configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/secureLogin").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Comment: Please confirm that you are hitting the "/login" endpoint when you are expecting this filter to engage.

Comment: I have a custom controller (which is basically writing a string) on /api/login and have the same behaviour. I tried /login as well (on which I didn't have defined anything) but it does not change: the filter is not hit.

Comment: Ok, so I found that this is actually called only if I use the default form login (adding `.formLogin()` to my configure method). I could then probably define a custom form but being a webservice application (the ui is managed elsewhere) I don't want to generate a login form here as I would like to use a rest call I already have... should I extend a different class then UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter? In that case is there a class I can use for my scenario or should I extend the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter class?

Comment: So, there are a couple of things here. The first is that, by default, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#attemptAuthentication is only called on /login, or on whatever is configured as the filterProcessesUrl--the filter may be rejecting the request in the requiresAuthentication method. Second, yes if this is for a rest call, then extending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is a little odd. If you take a look at successfulAuthentication, you'll see that the default successHandler wants to redirect the call when it is done. I'd probably just extend OncePerRequestFilter.

Comment: Thanks, I've resolved using AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter (see the updated on the post), but I'll take a look at the OncePerRequestFilter class you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You expect the filter to be triggered by accessing the path `api/secureLogin`. By default `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is triggered only by accessing `/login`.

If you add following line in the constructor of the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` which extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` it should work:

```java
  this.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/secureLogin");
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Mikyjpeg

You can use **UsernamePassWordAuthenticationFilter**. It does not have to be called from a form as you mentioned.

As long as it is called via a `POST` method with the url `/login` (instead of your `api/secureLogin` url), it will be executed.

The constructor uses a request matcher that only allows this url & request method:

```java
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
  super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your adding the configuration while overriding the configure method, try adding the filter mapping in your web.xml.  Something like this under the 'web-app' node:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>JWTAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.yourProject.JWTAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JWTAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't have any web.xml as I'm working with spring boot. Anyway the Configuration annotation shouldn't be needed and I probably left it there by mistake from a previous try, I'm going to remove it.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer by ADAM has worked for me. Those who are working with annotation based configuration can add following

```
@Override protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
   return new Filter[]{
        new JwtAuthenticationFilter()
   }; 
}
```

Into your AppInitialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BeforeAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public BeforeAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("api/secureLogin", "POST"));
        super.setFilterProcessesUrl("api/secureLogin");
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide more details and make sure to read [how to write good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before trying to answer any other question .

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, however, I've given this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078924/spring-security-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-not-replacing-defaul/75334292#75334292) to a similar question, so it can also be useful here: Your custom implementation extends the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (which in its turn extends the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, by default, is used for .formLogin authentication, handling the default AntRequestMatcher "/login". If you use a different protected endpoint, the filter's attemptAuthentication() method never gets action. So, if you want to use a different matcher (a different protected endpoint), you have to override the default AntRequestMatcher. For instance, you can do so within your custom filter constructor, by using something like that:

```
super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/signin", "GET"));
```