# Getting 403 forbidden after authentication using custom authentication filter that parses JSON payload

Tags: java, spring-security

What I'm trying to do is just authenticate in-memory default user using a custom authentication filter that parses a JSON payload that contain the username and the password.

***SecurityConfig.java***

```java
package ali.yousef.authdemo.config.security;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception
    {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();

        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception
    {
        JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter jsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter = new JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        jsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .addFilterAt(jsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

***JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter.java***

```java
package ali.yousef.authdemo.config.security;

public class JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{
    protected JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        UsernamePasswordDto usernamePasswordDto;

        try
        {
            usernamePasswordDto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernamePasswordDto.class);
            System.out.println(usernamePasswordDto.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usernamePasswordDto.getUsername(), usernamePasswordDto.getPassword());

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);
    }
}
```

***TestController.java***

```java
@RestController
public class TestController
{
    @GetMapping("/api/hello")
    public String hello(Principal principal)
    {
        return "hello " + principal.getName();
    }
}
```

When authenticating the default user it gets authenticated and return the home page but when I try to send a request to `/api/hello` it respond with `403`.

EDIT:
I edited how I register the custom authentication filter. But the same problem is present. It seems like the security context gets cleared after successful authentication and I get `anonymousUser` from principal.

Comment: 403 is an *authorization* failure response, as opposed to 401 which is an *authentication* failure. In other words, 401 means "I don't know who you are" whereas 403 means "I identified you but you don't have permission for that resource."

Comment: Thank you, yes I know this but the problem is getting 403 even though the user was authenticated and have the right permission to get access to `/api/hello` resource.

Comment: I must add when trying to get the principal name in an open resource I get anonymousUser.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a UsernamePassWordAuthenticationFilter brings in more customizations than you need to set up a custom auth filter.. see this post for more details why your filter is not getting called - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609233/custom-spring-security-filter-not-called-at-runtime)

You can achieve the same using OncePerRequestFilter as below -

```
@Component
public class JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = YOUR_LOGIC(); // new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("test", "passwd",Collections.emptyList()); as you have no authorities empty list is important here...
    
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter filter) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
          auth.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")).authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
        })  ;

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: The filter is getting called and it authenticates the user but when I send another request I get 403 or `anonymousUser`. Please check my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289494/getting-anonymous-user-after-authentication-with-custom-filter) post as I make things more clear

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to /api/hello your filter’s attemptAuthentication() never takes action. This is because your custom implementation extends the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (which in its turn extends the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, by default, is used for .formLogin authentication, and handles the default AntRequestMatcher "/login". Sending a request to /api/hello is an endpoint that is not handled by your filter. Since your security configuration requires that any /api/** endpoint should be authenticated, you receive the error. So, it should be made clear that an implementation of either UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter or AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, is usually being used for Authenticating a user.

However, you can use/add your testing /api/hello endpoint to your filter and confirm that it works. For instance, you can override the default “/login” AntRequestMatcher from within your custom filter constructor, by using something like that (use the appropriate for you Http action, GET, POST, etc:

```
protected JsonUserPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager); 
    super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/hello", "POST"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify I was authenticating against `/login`, I actually send a request to `/login` and get authenticated and when I send another request I get 403 or `anonymousUser` if the endpoint is not protected. Please check my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289494/getting-anonymous-user-after-authentication-with-custom-filter) post where I clarify things more.