# Getting anonymous user after authentication with custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have post this question but with different format and got no answer and I think I didn't provide enough info.

What I am trying to do is parse a login request payload that contain a JSON with username and password. So, I had to extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and replace the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` in filter chain with my custom filter.

I've done that and registered my custom filter as you can see in the log from `DefaultSecurityFilterChain`:

```
2023-01-30T22:33:13.993+03:00  INFO 20436 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1ec09a68, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7da9b32c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2b6ff016, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@118c1faa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4f5df012, ali.yousef.chatty.config.security.JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7e5c8c80, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a491a60, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4a0f4282, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@46df794e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@470866d1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1d0fc0bc]
```

Until now everything works fine.

Here is the code:

***SecurityConfig.java***

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter jsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        jsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(jsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

***JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java***

```java
public class JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordDto usernamePasswordDto;

        try {
            usernamePasswordDto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernamePasswordDto.class);
            logger.info(usernamePasswordDto.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(usernamePasswordDto.getUsername(), usernamePasswordDto.getPassword());

        Authentication result = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authToken);

        for (GrantedAuthority a : result.getAuthorities()) {
            logger.info(a.getAuthority());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

***TestController.java***

```java
@RestController
public class TestController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth == null)
            return "null";

        return auth.getName();
    }
}
```

I send a request to `/login` and I get `anonymousUser` response. I thought I missed something in the custom filter so I printed the authorities the user has and got `ROLE_USER`.

Here is the full output

```
2023-01-30T22:48:30.329+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] ali.yousef.chatty.ChattyApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-30T22:48:30.851+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-30T22:48:30.903+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-30T22:48:31.355+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-30T22:48:31.361+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-30T22:48:31.361+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-01-30T22:48:31.431+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-30T22:48:31.432+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1064 ms
2023-01-30T22:48:31.559+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-30T22:48:31.591+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-30T22:48:31.696+03:00  WARN 20900 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-01-30T22:48:31.781+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-30T22:48:31.983+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@77ea806f
2023-01-30T22:48:31.984+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-30T22:48:32.032+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-01-30T22:48:32.847+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-30T22:48:32.853+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-30T22:48:33.070+03:00  WARN 20900 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-01-30T22:48:33.220+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2023-01-30T22:48:33.519+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5cd6a827, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6cd65042, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5c30decf, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5aefdb9e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@50d6af87, ali.yousef.chatty.config.security.JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7674f9d4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4a0f4282, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@356ab368, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4b5ceb5d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@99f75e4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7da9b32c]
2023-01-30T22:48:33.688+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-30T22:48:33.689+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2023-01-30T22:48:33.690+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@5d3a238]]
2023-01-30T22:48:33.690+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2023-01-30T22:48:33.696+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [           main] ali.yousef.chatty.ChattyApplication      : Started ChattyApplication in 3.673 seconds (process running for 3.952)
2023-01-30T22:48:52.209+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-30T22:48:52.209+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-30T22:48:52.209+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2023-01-30T22:48:52.250+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : UsernamePasswordDto(username=user01, password=password)
2023-01-30T22:48:52.421+03:00  INFO 20900 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : ROLE_USER
```

What I think is after finishing the authentication process and sending a redirect to homepage the context is deleted somehow or cleared, but I'm not Spring Security expert.

I've done this in older versions with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` without any problem but using this way of configuration didn't work.

I really tried everything I could and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem from Marcus when I posted an issue on the spring security repository on github because I thought it was a bug. If you want to check the answer yourself you can go [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12636#issuecomment-1422569183)

The issue was that the my custom filter was using `RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository` but the default was `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository`, hence made the authentication not getting saved between requests.

Setting the `SecurityContextRepository` in `jsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository` will solve the issue.

```
jsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        ));
```

Comment: Nice hearing you solved the problem! (However, be aware, not to make your app stateful -of course, if you don’t wish to).

Comment: This didn't work for me :/ Is there anything else you did?

Answer (score 2):

The SecurityContext is not saved by default after successful authentication. Moreover, the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is a form-login-based mechanism, so the Authentication object cannot be detected by the SessionManagementFilter, as the filter is not invoked during the authenticating request. So, you query the wrong Authentication object which in your case defaults to an Anonymous user.

So, first, after a successful authentication you have to save the authenticated Authentication object(returned from the attemptAuthentication() method) in the Security Context. You can do that by overriding the successfulAuthentication() method of your filter.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,  jakarta.servlet.FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, jakarta.servlet.ServletException {

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authResult);
        //SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository secRepo = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
        secRepo.saveContext(context, request, response);

        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
}
```

You have to save it, in a persistent way, i.e. it has to be preserved during the whole session. A way to do so is via using an instance of the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository class and using its saveContext() method to save it.

After that, in your handler method for the default “/” home(), you can obtain the saved SecurityContextHolder, again by using an instance of the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository class and via its loadDeferredContext() method.

Note, that for this purpose, first, it is necessary to bring the request object (returned from your filter) in your handler home() method.  (For completeness you can do the same for the response object as well).

After that, you can obtain the authenticated user from the extracted security context.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String home(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                   jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) {
   
    //Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository secRepo = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    Authentication auth = secRepo.loadDeferredContext(request).get().getAuthentication();  

    if (auth == null) return "null";

    return (String) auth.getPrincipal();

}
```

One more thing that should be mentioned, is that if you want you can invalidate the session in your handler. This is a "must" for security reasons, especially if you use a STATELESS application e.g.a REST API application.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you for you help, the authentication is saved in the parent class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/c4485a8909119f88559dd4200cd3506024749529/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L320). I just got the solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12636#issuecomment-1422569183). The issue was that the default `SecurityContextRepository` was changed to `DelegatingSecurityContextRepository` and I had to set it myself.